# Using Zurb Foundation - On iPad, html tag restricted to 768

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm currently using Zurb Foundation 4 for a website and have had no problems with it until now.

The website i'm working on is displaying correctly on iPhone, Androids etc however on an iPad, the html tag is being restricted to a max of 768px with the content still acting responsively as it hits the edge of the iPad screen.

Is this value set in Zurb somewhere as it's currently breaking the site.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you are having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using modernizr to detect what device i was using. It's a weird situation as the client only wanted an iphone site but wanted the site coded to work fine independently on iPad and desktop.